# In non-native applications, in the Open File dialog, I can see hidden files but I can't select them

Tags: macos, finder, dialog

I have a problem with some non-native mac software (Perforce Diff and Kdiff3).

When I use the Open File Dialog, I can see the hidden files, but I can not select them or interact with them at all.

In contrast, when using the native Mac TextEdit, when I use the Open File Dialog, I can see and open the hidden files.

---

This is a screenshot of the Kdiff3 Open File Dialog. I can see the hidden files, but I can not select them.

[image: I can see hidden files but I can not select them]

---

OS X version 10.10.3 Yosemite.

I did this to make Finder show hidden files

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

I did this to make the file open dialog show hidden files

```
defaults write -g AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can often alt/option click on files to force open them.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. In this case option-click still does not allow me to select the files in the File Open Dialog. Right-click allows me to do a Quick Look, but will not allow me to select the files for opening.

Comment: It works in some software.